# How can i install software from a script in powershell as admin from remote

Tags: powershell

I want this to run without any interaction as admin? How can i run a powershell script on a remote machine with admin rights?

```
$Path = $env:TEMP; $Installer = "dotner_installer.exe"; Invoke-WebRequest "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2088631" -OutFile $Path\$Installer; Start-Process -FilePath $Path\$Installer -Args "/y /silent /install" -Verb RunAs -Wait; Remove-Item $Path\$Installer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you connect via PSSession your session on the remote computer has by default administrator rights. Use `Invoke-Command` to execute your script directly on the target or `Enter-PSSession` to do it manually. You can create a session with `New-PSSession` to store the session in a variable and use it for multiple cmdlets.

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName targetPC #-Credential if\needed


Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
    $Path = $env:TEMP; 
    $Installer = "dotner_installer.exe"; 
    Invoke-WebRequest "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2088631" -OutFile $Path\$Installer; 
    Start-Process -FilePath $Path\$Installer -Args "/y /silent /install" -Verb RunAs -Wait; 
    Remove-Item $Path\$Installer 
} -ArgumentList $IfYouHaveSome
```

Comment: i am connecting to an azure vm via a pipeline so it will be non interactive, it will be runnin g without interative mode , i dont think the above will work

Comment: @itye1970 now it's 100% none interactive... If PSSession is enabled (`Enable-PSSession`) on the Azure VM it should work there too... If it does not worke use [Invoke-AzVMCommand](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/powershell-basics-connecting-to-vms-with-azure-psremoting/ba-p/428403)